# I am making a whatsapp chat analyser. I have made the pattern which supports 24-hour chat format. I want it to support 12-hour chat format as well

Tags: python, regex, nlp, analytics, python-re

When one will upload 24-hour chat format, my analyser accepts it.
`9/5/21, 22:26 -`

This is the format and the pattern I have written is

```
r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s-\s|\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[APap][Mm]\s-\s
```

Provide me the pattern that supports this format: `02/03/2023, 9:56 pm -`

Comment: what did you try? If you want both formats then maybe create two regex and check one after another.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to use module `datetime` and function `strptime` (string parsing time)

Comment: I was thinking to suggest `pattern1|pattern2` but it seems you already use it to match two different patterns. If your patterns don't works then maybe your data don't match to patterns. Maybe you don't have spaces or `-` in dates

Comment: if patterns doesn't work then maybe you should start with shorter version - ie. only date or only time am/pm - and check if this part works, and later add next element to see when it has problem with matching full pattern. OR maybe you should use `() ` like `(pattern1)|(pattern2)` to make sure it works with full patterns.